# Customize `::-webkit-scrollbar` inline with React

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar, inline

How can I apply the `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo elements to a component using inline styling in React?

Comment: One cannot write `pesudo` selectors as `inline` styles..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't write `pseudo` selector inline, you need to add it in css. Refer this [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore)

Comment: According to the answer of @Elena this is not correct

Comment: "Page not found" When visiting this 'link'

Answer (score 15):

This worked in my project `'&::WebkitScrollbar': { width: 0, }`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to explain your answers rather than just post code. When answering an older question with other, accepted answers, also explain how your answer is different or an improvement/update on the others.

Comment: seems that it doesn't work in pure React

Answer (score 2):

React suggests this

```
<div style={{ '&::WebkitScrollbar': { width: 0, height: 0 } }}></div>
```

Comment: not sure why I received a negative vote, that is what React suggests on console when I try to add "webkit-scrollbar", and it works

Comment: Could you please add a link to a source