# React MUI v5 - unable to hide scrollbar on specific page only

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar, hide

I try to hide the vertical scrollbar on one page (component) only.
I use `"react": "^18.2.0"` and `"@mui/material": "5.10.4"` (MUI v5).

Last thing I tried was to style the parent div - for which I used a `Box` component directly, which did not do anything:

```
return (
    <Box 
    component="div"
    sx={{
        overflowX: "hidden",
        overflowY:"auto",
        '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
            display: "none"
        }
    }}>
        ... content ...
    </Box>
)
```

Similar this did not work (from solution here: [Customize `::-webkit-scrollbar` inline with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345981/customize-webkit-scrollbar-inline-with-react)):

```
<div style={{ '&::WebkitScrollbar': { width: 0, height: 0 } }}></div>
```

Before I tried adding a `.css` as suggested in this solution: [How to hide scroll bar in react app with allowing scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111024/how-to-hide-scroll-bar-in-react-app-with-allowing-scrolling)

But this also did not do anything:

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        ... content ...
    </div>
)
```

The only thing that workes was to add a global property to the .css file but this is hiding the scrollbar on every page and also does not work on firefox.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Set these CSS rules to the specific page component

```
with: 0 !important;
background-color: transparent; /* optional */
```

Don't forget to add `::-webkit-scrollbar` pseudo-element to that class.

example:

```
<Box class="hideme"></Box>
```

CSS:

```
.hideme::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0 !important;
    background-color: transparent; /* optional */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't use `class`, I have to use 'className'. I get this warning: `react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Invalid DOM property class. Did you mean className?` Nevertheless, I tried with your suggestions and `className="hideme"` but nothing happens.